# What is the convention for table and column names in HSQLDB when using grails?

Tags: grails, naming-conventions, hsqldb

If I have a `FooBar` entity with a `fizzBuzz` field, what will the resulting table and column names be in HSQL?  Would they be `FOO_BAR` and `FIZZ_BUZZ`?  Or `FooBar` and `fizzBuzz`?  Or . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following domain class:

```
class MyDomain
{
    String myField
}
```

Creates the following structure (as viewed in the DatabaseManager):

[image: Table Structure]

So your first example is correct, the table created is `FOO_BAR` and the field is `FIZZ_BUZZ`.

Comment: I actually found the names all lower case on my machine, but I suspect it isn't case sensitive.